# Need to code sliding jquery to display multiple content divs not seen

Tags: jquery, animation

I put together the following fiddle located here:
http://jsfiddle.net/96U7Q/

```
.site1 img{width:300px; height:197px;}
.site2 img{width:300px; height:197px;}
.site1link{background-color:#CCC;width:300px; height:167px;}
.site1link:hover{background-color:#FFF;}
.site2link{background-color:#333;width:300px; height:167px;}
.site2link:hover{background-color:#FFF;}
```

and the two sqaures will be two different aspects of the site.  Where I need help is coding a jquery animation using something similar to this

```
$('.site1').animate({left: "100%"}, 2000, 'swing', function()
```

What I need is if the link for "Site 1" is clicked it slides off to the left (out of the viewers eye because it will contain graphics that don't need to be seen anymore), and a div containing the content for site 1 would slide into the center of the page and be the only thing visible.  If the link for "Site 2" is clicked it slides off to the right the same as Site 1, and the content for "Site 2" would slide in from the right into the center of the page the same way.

While on each "section" or site - I'll need a link to return back to the "main" stage which shows the links to both sites again for easy navigation.

I've really researched jquery and how to animate divs, but this seems to be a bit more in-depth than what's out there.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Did you try adding some jQuery ?

Comment: I don't see any in your Fiddle.

Comment: Don't get rude with people who are only asking questions in order to help you.  You don't have any jQuery anyplace in your jsFiddle, so don't expect anyone to write it for you.  Also please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry putvande, I was working with several fiddles and the link I posted didn't have the jquery in it (my apologies)...not asking anyone to write code for me sparky, just asking for direction...I don't believe I said "please write it all for me"

Answer (score 0):

I think your animation problem is simply a couple syntax errors. Namely, you're missing some quotes. So, to correct the example you gave (note, I also changed this so that the container will animate left the number of pixels it is wide):

```
$('.site1').animate({'left': '-=300px'}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTu92/

Oh, I also change the `href` attribute on `div.site1` to `"#"` instead of `""`, to avoid an error.

Comment: That's great, thank you! I'm wondering if to simplify things the " alert('sweet');" should actually just redirect to another URL with content rather than "swinging" back in the related content.  These will be 2 independent sites but of the same company.

Comment: Firstly, I'm glad to see that you apologized for your off-color comment. It's a good rule to always be courteous, period. Secondly, the function of the animate method can be whatever you want it to be. I just put the alert there to have something there. You could have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LTu92/11/

Comment: No problem, I was just shocked at the down vote from the first comment, then the internet police arrived to diffuse the situation :)  Thank you for your comment, and I found "window.location.replace" in a search, but now the project has changed so I'll be looking into an ajax solution to be able to load other content dynamically.

Comment: I see that this doesn't work in Firefox 30 or IE 11.  Does anyone have any suggestions to make it cross browser compatible?

Comment: You were repeating yourself in your CSS and some styles weren't being applied. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTu92/177/